# Internet explorer 11 or IE 8 showing different webpage layout compared to chrome or mozilla

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, razor

I am coding a webpage using cshtml which has a link which points to doc or pdf file in windows server location. In windows explorer, I am able to open the file by clicking the link. But in chrome or mozilla, I am not able to open the file. After searching in SO, I understood that the local files cannot be opened in chrome or firefox because of security reason.

I was okay with it. But the problem is the layout of the page is not dispalying properly in **Internet Explorer 11 or 8**.

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
@{
    var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Issues.txt");
    Array userData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);

}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\styles.css">
</head>


<body>

<table width="1084" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><h1><strong> Bug Analysis Helper Tool</strong></h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="abc"  width="1085" height="464" border="0">
  <tr id=abc>
    <td width="139" valign=top >Shows how to approach an issue</td>
    <td width="936" rowspan="2" valign=top>
    <h2>Types of Issues</h2>
@foreach (string dataLine in userData)
{

    int i = 0;

    string[] words = dataLine.Split(',');
    string[] a = new string[2];
    foreach (string dataItem in words)
    {

        a[i] = @dataItem;
        i++;
    }
      
    <a href="@a[1]"> @a[0] </a> <br/>
                             
 }
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
table.abc
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 78pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-indent: 10px;  
    background-color:#000000;
}
body
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #000000;
}
p
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-indent: 20px;
}
h1
{
    color: #000099;
    font-family:Segoe UI, Arial, Times New Roman;
    font-size: 26pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
h2
{
    color: #FF6600;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
td
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #000000;
}

th
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #000000;
}
```

(Didnt try in other version of IE)

Comment: you are obv using a stylesheet. You should provide us with that as well, because your code yields the same results in IE, ff & chrome otherwise. You may want to provide which version of IE you do mean.

Comment: The given HTML/CSS do not even look like your picture, could you assemble a simple example using HTML & CSS **Only**?

Comment: @Goodwine thats my code

Answer (score 1):

Give units for all tags width like below.

```
   <table width="1084px" border="0">
```